# python tuple nest is producing random output

Tags: python, nested, tuples

I am new to Python. I created `Tuple1` and want to nest with the `Tuple2`
while nesting if i do not enclose last character in tuple which need to be nested  is giving irrelevant output instead of nesting 2 Tuples

please have a look at the code below.
please let me know why it is behaving in such a way? is it expected behavior ?

```
>>> tuple1 = 1, 2, 3, 'hello' 
>>> tuple1 (1, 2, 3, 'hello') 
>>>  
>>> tuple2 = tuple1, (4, 5, 'a', 6, 'b', 7 , c) 
>>> tuple2 ((1, 2, 3, 'hello'), (4, 5, 'a', 6, 'b', 7, [(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)])) 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> tuple2 = tuple1, (4, 5, 'a', 6, 'b', 7 , 'c') 
>>> tuple2 ((1, 2, 3, 'hello'), (4, 5, 'a', 6, 'b', 7, 'c')) 
>>>
```

Comment: >>> tuple1 = 1, 2, 3, 'hello'
>>> tuple1
(1, 2, 3, 'hello')
>>>

>>> tuple2 = tuple1, (4, 5, 'a', 6, 'b', 7 , c)
>>> tuple2
((1, 2, 3, 'hello'), (4, 5, 'a', 6, 'b', 7, [(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]))
>>>
>>>
>>> tuple2 = tuple1, (4, 5, 'a', 6, 'b', 7 , 'c')
>>> tuple2
((1, 2, 3, 'hello'), (4, 5, 'a', 6, 'b', 7, 'c'))
>>>

Comment: you should format your code - [look at stackoverflow help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: Use the [edit] button to add code or make improvements to your question rather than adding it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

this will make a tuple of tuples:

```
tuple2 = tuple1, (4, 5, 'a', 6, 'b', 7 , 'c')
```

This will unite the tuples into one:

```
tuple2 = tuple1 + (4, 5, 'a', 6, 'b', 7 , 'c')
```

Comment: Thanks Kostas,    remove single quotes from c, then the output is different.                                                                                                              >>> tuple2 = tuple1, (4, 5, 'a', 6, 'b', 7 , c)
>>> tuple2
((1, 2, 3, 'hello'), (4, 5, 'a', 6, 'b', 7, [(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]))                                      why the above result is different

Comment: @umer You cannot remove the quotes from c. That could only happen if c was a variable and only then. It's a `string` character. Only numbers can be represented without quotes. Why do you even want to remove quotation?